# Web Service SOAP

Tags: php, web-service, soap, zend, soapclient

Estou com um problema muito incomum com uma aplicação SOAP. Tenho um client simples para fazer um teste de consumo.

Quando eu testo diretamente na view action do service me retorna o resultado corretamente, porem quando tento consumir a mesma funcionalidade por um client ele me retorna `null`.

Olhei o *PHP error log* no wamp, e da o seguinte erro:

> Undefined variable: json in C:\wamp64\www\service-stsc\module\WebService\src\WebService\Api\WebServiceApi.php on line 591

**OBS:** Tenho outras funções neste mesmo service e estão funcionando normalmente.

*Client:*

**analise.php**

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/service-stsc/webservice/soap?wsdl');

 var_dump($result = $client->__soapCall('ConsultaAnalitica', array( 
       '2017-06-05', 
       '2017-06-05')
 ));
```

*Server:*

**TSCCOntroller.php**

```
public function analiseAction()
    {
        try
        {
            $webServiceApi = new WebServiceApi(array(TSCController::$TSCModel => $this->getModel(TSCController::$TSCModel)));
            echo $webServiceApi->ConsultaAnalitica($dataInicial,$dataFinal);

            exit;
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex)
        {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**WebServiceApi.php**

```
public function ConsultaAnalitica($dataInicial, $dataFinal)
{
    try{
        if (($tscs = $this->TSC->ConsultaAnaliticaSQL($dataInicial, $dataFinal)) != null){                    
            foreach ($tscs as $tsc)
            {
                $array[$tsc->DataHora] = $tsc->Quantidade;
                $json = json_encode($array);
            }

            return $json; <-- LINHA 591
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex)
    {
        $this->Log->Ocorrencia = 2;
        $this->Log->Motivo = 'Problemas na consulta de tsc por data hora através do serviço de integração. Detalhes: ' . $ex->getMessage();

        $this->Log->insertToLog($this->Log->toArray());

        return false;
    }
}
```

**TSCModel.php**

```
public function ConsultaAnaliticaSQL($dataInicial, $dataFinal){
        try{
            $sqlTSC = "SELECT DataHoraOcorrencia as DataHora, COUNT(TSC.ID) as Quantidade FROM TSC WHERE DataHoraOcorrencia BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal' GROUP BY DATE(TSC.DataHoraOcorrencia)";
            $TSC = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($sqlTSC,array());
            return $TSC;

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$tscs` é vazio não entra não `foreach` e não cria a variável `$json`. Eu não compararia com null usaria um `empty()`. Ou defina um valor padrão para `$json`

Comment: Mas quando acesso minha analiseAction (que está no TSCController) que está dentro do service, ele me retorna o valor em json. Só me retorna null quando acesso por um client.